# $F$ be the smallest subfield of the real numbers which contains irrational $a$. Prove that $F$ is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, field-theory

Let $a$ be an irrational number and let $F$ be the smallest subfield of the real numbers
which contains $a$. Prove that $F$ is countable.

Comment: Check that the collection of rational functions $p(x)/q(x)$, with $p,q$ polynomials with rational coefficients, is countable. Check then that $F=\{p(a)/q(a): q(a)\ne0\}$.

Comment: Löwenheim-Skolem might be overkill, I suppose...

Comment: I don't think I have enough knowledge in set theory to prove the set of rational functions are countable. Also how do you know that this F would be the smallest subfield to contain a.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the smallest subfield (even though it is).  If a field contains the irrational a and is countable then it must be the case that the smallest field containing a is countable.

Answer (score 1):

Define $F_0 = \mathbb{Q} \cup \{a\}$, which is clearly countable, as the union of a countable set and a finite set.

Having defined $F_n$, define $F_{n+1}$ by $$F_{n+1} = \{x+y: x,y \in F_n\} \cup \{-x: x \in F_n\} \cup \{x\cdot y: x,y \in F_n\} \cup \{\frac{1}{x}: x \in F_n, x \neq 0\}$$

This defines a sequence of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and they are all countable, as shown by induction: $F_0$ is countable, as stated, and if $F_n$ is, so is $F_{n+1}$: we only need to show that each of the four sets of the union is countable (a countable or finite union of countable sets is countable). For the sets of inverses and negatives this is clear (we have a bijection with $F_n$ or a subset thereof), and for the sums and products it's easy to see as $+$ and $\cdot$ form surjections from $F_n \times F_n$ onto these sets resp. (and a product of two countable sets is countable).

Also, handy to observe: $F_n \subset F_{n+1}$, as $x = x + 0$, and $0$ is in all $F_n$ (we could have defined $F_n$ to be the fifth of the sets in the defining union of $F_{n+1}$ as well, if we're lazy).

Now, $F = \cup_n F_n$ is countable (as a countable union of countable sets again) and is a field: e.g. let $x, y \in F$, so $x \in F_n, y \in F_m$ for some $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$. Then by the increasingness, setting $k = \max(n,m) \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that $x,y \in F_k$, so by definition, $x + y \in F_{k+1} \subset F$ as well. Similarly for multiplication, inversion and negation, plus we already have $0$ and $1$.

And it's the smallest field as well, because if $G$ is any field containg the rationals and $a$, then $F_0 \subset G$, and then by induction $F_n \subset G$ for all $G$, as $G$ is closed under all field operations already. So $F \subset G$. This last step is not strictly necessary to see that the *smallest* such field is countable, as we already see there exists at least one countable such field, so the smallest one would be a subset so also countable... But it's nice to know, anyway. We added no more than needed to make $F$ a field.

This idea of "exhausting", i.e. adding points to make a set closed under some operations(s), is a very common technique, and is one of the motivating examples to start using ordinal numbers later, e.g.